# 'builder' is not defined no-undef Search for the keywords to learn more about each error

Tags: reactjs

```
export const cryptoApi=createApi({
    reducerPath:'cryptoApi',
    baseQuery:fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl}),
    endpoints:(builder)=>({
        getCrypto:builder.query({
            query:()=>createRequest('/coins')
        })
    })
});
```

*Error:
ERROR in [eslint]
src\services\cryptoApi.js
Line 17:16:  'builder' is not defined  no-undef

Line 18:19:  'builder' is not defined  no-undef*

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

**Compelete Code**

```
import {createApi,fetchBaseQuery} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

const cryptoApiHeaders = {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': '***',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com'
}

const baseUrl='https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coins'

const createRequest=(url)=>({url,headers:cryptoApiHeaders})

export const cryptoApi=createApi({
    reducerPath:'cryptoApi',
    baseQuery:fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl}),
    endpoints:(builder)=>({
        getCrypto:builder.query({
            query:()=>createRequest('/coins')
        })
    })
});

export const {
    useGetCryptoQuery,
}= cryptoApi;
```

I searched for error which force me to change internal varibale of elint node modules files.
This error shows builder var error.
I didn't get it.